# StartPosition of a non top-level Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The start position of the child form can't be set even if I manually programmed it this way:

```
f = new Home_Button_Forms.Home_Mandated_Organization();
f.TopLevel = false;
f.Parent = panel1;
f.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
f.Show();
```

It still appears in upper left corner of the panel1 (Parent Form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to move a form which is not top level, to center of it's container panel, you can set `Location` of form manually:

```
var f = new Form2();
f.TopLevel = false;
f.Parent = this.panel1;
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
f.Location = new Point((this.panel1.Width - f.Width) / 2, 
                       (this.panel1.Height - f.Height) / 2);
f.Show();
```